# VueJS webpack build error SCSS related

Tags: symfony, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, yarnpkg

I'm having errors when I try to build my VueJS project with the style sheets.

My error when I run "yarn run dev --watch" produces these errors:

```
c:\wamp\www\DBViewer2>yarn run dev --watch
yarn run v1.6.0
warning package.json: No license field
$ encore dev --progress=true --watch
Running webpack ...

  0% compiling
Webpack is watching the files…
                                                                                                                                   95% emitting ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                 16:00:56

This dependency was not found:

* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":true}!scss-loader!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./App.vue in ./assets/App.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"optionsId":"0","vue":true,"scoped":false,"sourceMap":true}!scss-loader!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./A
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. It appears it is looking for the files in the wrong location?

Here is my App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style lang="scss-loader">
  /* Import Font Awesome Icons Set */
  $fa-font-path: 'font-awesome/fonts/';
  @import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
  /* Import Simple Line Icons Set */
  $simple-line-font-path: 'simple-line-icons/fonts/';
  @import 'simple-line-icons/scss/simple-line-icons.scss';
  /* Import Bootstrap Vue Styles */
  @import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
  /*// Import Main styles for this application*/
  @import './assets/scss/style';
</style>
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public_html/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // will create public/build/app.js and public/build/app.css
    .addEntry('main', './assets/main.js')
    .addEntry('vendor', './assets/js/vendor.js')

    // allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // enable source maps during development
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    // empty the outputPath dir before each build
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

    // show OS notifications when builds finish/fail
    .enableBuildNotifications()

    // create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    // .enableVersioning()
    .enableVueLoader()
    // allow sass/scss files to be processed
    .enableSassLoader()
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated. Have spent 2 days now trying different things and research on google. I'm just not familiar enough with symfony/encore and this is my first vuejs project.

Comment: Instead of `<style lang="scss-loader">` try `<style lang="scss">`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use SCSS in a Vue template, you need to declare in the single file component the following `style` block:

```
<!-- Those styles are not scoped to that particular component -->
<style lang="scss">...</style>
<!-- Or those styles are scoped to that particular component -->
<style lang="scss" scoped>...</style>
```

You can even use both in the same file, if needed.

You'll also need to install the correct node dependencies by running:

```
npm install --dev node-sass sass-loader
```

This should then work out of the box when used in a project initialized with `vue-cli`.

However you [could need](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/724) to add this in your webpack 'test' configuration to make `lang="scss"` work in tests when using vue-loader's ?inject option:

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'scss-loader': 'sass-loader',
    },
},
```